# Change Windows 8 codepage in Python 3 Spyder console from cp1252 to utf-8

Tags: python, encoding, windows-8, utf-8, spyder

How does one change Windows 8 codepage in Python 3 Spyder console from cp1252 to utf-8?

The code page apparently is cp1252 as evidenced with

```
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

This means that it is difficult to print non-ascii characters with 'print' as an exception is raised (`UnicodeEncodeError`).

One possible solution is with the .encode method and its 'errors' argument.

```
u'\x9d'.encode('cp1252', errors='replace')
```

But why isn't there an (or where is the) option to change the console encoding to utf-8. I was expecting an option in the 'Preferences'.

Another solution is to execute the python file outside Spyder with like:

```
chcp 65001
c:\path_to_python\python.exe the_script.py
```

This works but lacks the integratedness of Spyder.

I tried to make a batch file with

```
chcp 65001
c:\path_to_python\python.exe
```

And set that to "use the following Python interpreter" in "Advanced settings", but Spyder would not allow it - at least the way I tried it.

I neither could make another workaround working by making a batch script with:

```
chcp 65001
c\:path_to_spyder\Spyder.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) This will be fixed in our next release (i.e. version *2.3.2*). Both input and output in the console will be treated as unicode from that release onwards, for Python 3 and Python 2 as well.